# Unable to connect Netapp (8.1.4P1 7-Mode) with jdk1.8.0_181

Tags: storage, netapp

We have below security configuration at storage side (8.1.4P1 7-Mode)

## Configurations

```
tls.enable on
ssl.enable on
ssl.v2.enable off
ssl.v3.enable off
```

We tried to access storage using NetApp Manageability SDK 5.7 and it is working fine with jdk1.8.0_161.

We upgrade  JDK to  jdk1.8.0_181 and then we are not able to access it, Its throwing Exception

```
`2018-08-03 05:06:27,071 [Thread-1469] app-ERROR-javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Connection has been shutdown: `javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException`: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure at` `sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.checkEOF(SSLSocketImpl.java:1551)`

    at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(AppInputStream.java:95)

    at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(AppInputStream.java:71)

    at netapp.manage.http.HTTPMessage.readLine(HTTPMessage.java:245)

    at netapp.manage.http.HTTPResponse.read(HTTPResponse.java:74)

    at netapp.manage.http.HTTPClient.doRequest(HTTPClient.java:772)

    at netapp.manage.NaServer.invokeHTTP(NaServer.java:955)
```

As per  release notes of jdk  "jdk1.8.0_181",  JDK 181 disabled "3DES cipher suites".

Is there any way to fix it from NetApp side ?

Comment: Removed salutation and unnecessary empty lines

Answer (score 0):

While not an answer to the direct question of how to solve this from the NetApp side, the problem can be overcome on the application side by removing "3DES_EDE_CBC" from the jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms security property at runtime. Something like:

```
final String JDK_TLS_DISABLED_ALGORITHMS = "jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms";
final String TRIPLE_DES_EDE_CBC = "3DES_EDE_CBC";
final String disabledAlgorithms = Splitter.on(',').trimResults()
        .splitToList(Security.getProperty(JDK_TLS_DISABLED_ALGORITHMS)).stream()
        .filter(algo -> !algo.equals(TRIPLE_DES_EDE_CBC)).collect(joining(", "));
Security.setProperty(JDK_TLS_DISABLED_ALGORITHMS, disabledAlgorithms);
```